# How can I align content to right inside v-col?

Tags: vuetify.js

In the document, justify-** and align-** are design for determine where the grid block should be placed, but how can I make the content inside the v-col align to right?

Comment: Please show some effort by editing your question and explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a small example that aligns content to the right inside v-col (in this case a close button):

```
<v-row>
    <v-col align="right">
        <v-btn color="error">X</v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Or with multiple columns:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="9">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3" align="right">
        <v-btn color="error">X</v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

So you simply need to add

> align="right"

as a parameter at v-col to align content to the right side within a v-col.

Comment: Confirming that this works nicely for me.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late to this. I came here for a solution and ended up RTM.  align="right" doesn't work for all components inside v-col.  The way to left/right/center align is to use v-spacer.  If you want to right align, add a v-spacer to the left of your component inside of v-col.  v-col also needs d-flex class.

```
<v-app>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="8">
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="d-flex" cols="4">
        <v-spacer />
        <!-- insert any other content here to right align inside this col -->
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
<v-app>
```

You can also add the class `.text-right` if you're trying to align a button or text

Comment: Good solution! It helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code of the [Playground](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids#playground) example in Vuetify's Grid System page, you could put an EXTRA `v-row` inside your `v-col`, and use `justify-**` in this newly added `v-row`. E.g.:

```
<v-app>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <!-- first column -->
      <v-col cols="8">
        <!-- the extra row -->
        <v-row justify="center">
          <p>Your Content</p>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="4">
        Second column
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
<v-app>
```

Or, if the `v-col` is the ONLY column in your first-level `v-row`, you MAY get rid of that, just put your content in the `v-row` to which you can apply the `justify`. E.g.:

```
<v-app>
  <v-container>
    <v-row justify="center">
      <p>Your Content</p>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
<v-app>
```